# android - change visibility of listView

Tags: android, listview, visibility

I have a listView with countries as Strings.

```
lv = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.listViewCountry);
        ArrayList<String> arrayCountry = new ArrayList<>();
        arrayCountry.addAll(Arrays.asList(getResources().getStringArray(R.array.array_country)));

        adapter = new ArrayAdapter<>(
                MainActivity.this,
                android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,
                arrayCountry);
        lv.setAdapter(adapter);
```

I have a searchView on the toolbar.

```
@Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        MenuItem item = menu.findItem(menuSearch);
        SearchView searchView = (SearchView)item.getActionView();

        searchView.setOnQueryTextListener(new SearchView.OnQueryTextListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String query) {
                return false;
            }

            @Override
            public boolean onQueryTextChange(String newText) {
                adapter.getFilter().filter(newText);
                return false;
            }
        });


        return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
    }
```

When the app starts, I need my Visibility of my listView GONE and when I press search in the toolbar the listView should be VISIBLE.

Do I have to do anything with `onOptionsItemSelected`,

```
@Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == menuSearch) {
            lv.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
```

But my code is not working...

main.xml...

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

    <item android:id="@+id/menuSearch"
        android:title="Search"
        android:icon="@android:drawable/ic_menu_search"
        app:actionViewClass="android.widget.SearchView"
        app:showAsAction="always">
    </item>
</menu>
```

Comment: set empty textview in listview so if list is empty it will show empty message or no meesage

Comment: I think you should put the code to make the listview visible in `onOptionsItemSelected` ?

Comment: @nabillondon, yeah I think that to.. But what I have done is not working..

Comment: @Simon maybe `onOptionsItemSelected` isn't being called, do you have `app:showAsAction="always|collapseActionView"` in your searchview xml definition?

Comment: did that but negative result.. still listview is gone...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `setOnSearchClickListener` for your `SearchView`

```
@Override
public void onCreate() {
     ...
     yourListView.setVisibility(View.GONE); // or use View.INVISIBLE 
}
...
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
     SearchView searchView = (SearchView)item.getActionView();
     searchView.setOnSearchClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            lv.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: @Simon can you explain more about `not working`. I think it should work

Comment: @Simon I still don't know why this happened. try `setOnTouchListener` instead of `setOnClickListener`

Comment: @Simon do you have a demo project. can you share it to me. I will try to check on your code

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/137306/discussion-between-simon-and-phan-van-linh).

Comment: @Simon I have update my answer, it work in your demo project, please check it

Comment: Hi Simon, I'm currently having the same issue you had. I can't seem to close listView inside setOnCloseListener. What did you do to make it work finally?

Answer (score 1):

if you want to set a view to be invisible, you may try:

```
lv.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
```

or

```
lv.setVisibility(View.GONE);
```

In your case, you can set the lv to be invisible in onCreate, 
and set listview to be visible in onQueryTextSubmit.

```
  @Override
  public void onCreate() {
     //... others
     lv.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
  }


  @Override
  public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String query) {
       lv.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
       return false;
  }
```

Setup on close listener:

```
searchView.setOnCloseListener(new SearchView.OnCloseListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onClose() {
                lv.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                return false;
            }
        });
```

Comment: Sir, this code makes listView Visible when I type the word and press the search button. But what I actually need is, when I press the search in the toolbar the listView should be Visible.

Comment: When I close the searchView the listView is Visible... How can I make it GONE when I close the searchVierw...

Comment: @Simon Did you solve your problem? please tell me if you need any helps.

Comment: you may consider storing an ArrayList<String>, which used to store the items searched recently.

When user clicked 'search', search it -> add into the arraylist when results come back.

And of course, you can limit the number of items searched recently by checking the arraylist.size()

Comment: When I press back button I need to close searchView... I have tried many concepts but it doesn't seem to work... plz help me...

Answer (score 0):

try this
listview.visible = false;
or you can change in listview properties..
find visible and set false

Answer (score 0):

Add:

```
item.setOnMenuItemClickListener(new MenuItem.OnMenuItemClickListener()
{
    @Override 
    public boolean onMenuItemClick(MenuItem menuItem) { 
         Toast.makeText(this, "Click", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
         lv.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE); return false;
    }
});
```

in onCreateOptionsMenu

Comment: I can't add toast to onClickListner method... It shows `cannot reslove method makeText'...

Comment: item .setOnMenuItemClickListener(new MenuItem.OnMenuItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onMenuItemClick(MenuItem menuItem) { Toast.makeText(this, "Click", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show(); lv.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                return false;
            }
        });